# SQL to group ypositions by frequency

Tags: sql, oracle, math

I am upgrading a modelling system and have an issue with the models drawing three sides of a rectangle between nodes, rather than going straight. I have worked out that I can resolve this by updating the yposition to all be on a line and the software will redraw the model correctly. But the distance between 2 parallel lines can vary from model to model. If in the SQL below I make the range to large I bring items from the next line down into this line. If I make it too small I do not bring all items from this line into line. So I need a way to automagically find the groupings of ypositions.

E.g. I can run the following code improve the situation in most cases

```
update hewlett_22.gm_object_point t1
     set t1.yposition = (select case
           when yposition between -500 and -401 then -450 
           when yposition between -400 and -301 then -350 
           when yposition between -300 and -201 then -250 
           when yposition between -200 and -101 then -150 
           when yposition between -100 and -1 then -50
           when yposition = 0  then 0            
           when yposition between 1 and 100 then 50 
           when yposition between 101 and 200 then 150
           when yposition between 201 and 300 then 250
           when yposition between 301 and 400 then 350
           when yposition between 401 and 500 then 450
           when yposition between 501 and 600 then 550
           else yposition
         end as row_group 
    from hewlett_22.gm_object_point op  
    where op.csmver = (select max(csmver) from hewlett_22.gm_object_point op2 where op2.CSMMRID = op.CSMMRID)
       and op.CSMMRID = t1.CSMMRID
       and op.sequencenumber = t1.sequencenumber)
```

But in some of the models the range of my between is too large and in others too small. If I identify a diagram with ypositions clustered around a range of 50 (when yposition between 1 and 50 then 25) and update the case ... between to have a narrower range these models are good. If I then take another model and increase the range to 200 ( when yposition between 1 and 200 then 100) these models are good.

I believe that if I knew more about maths I could write a query that was more dynamic in its range but I have not been able to. Is anyone able to offer suggestions how to rewrite it?

```
E.g. model 1

              |---|
X--|    |--X--|   |--X
   |----|

X--|  |--X
   |--|

Model 2

X--|    |--X--|     |--
   |    |     |--X--|
   |----|

X--X--|  |--X--|
      |--|     |     |--X
               |--X--|
```

In both cases the idea is to end up with all elements on one line, e.g. the list line above becomes.

X--X------X----X----X

Answer (score 1):

To generalize your CASE statement it appears you'd want to use

```
set t1.yposition = (TRUNC(ABS(YPOSITION)-1, -2) + 50) * SIGN(YPOSITION)
```

A more general form would be

```
WITH cteInterval_width AS (SELECT 25 AS INTERVAL_WIDTH FROM DUAL),
     cteConstants AS (SELECT INTERVAL_WIDTH,
                             100 / INTERVAL_WIDTH AS INTERVAL_DIVISOR
                        FROM cteInterval_width),
     ctePositions AS (SELECT LEVEL AS LVL,
                             DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-1000, 1000) AS YPOSITION FROM DUAL
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25)
SELECT LVL,
       YPOSITION,
       (TRUNC(ABS(YPOSITION*INTERVAL_DIVISOR)-1, -2)/INTERVAL_DIVISOR) AS TRUNC_TO_WIDTH,
       ((TRUNC(ABS(YPOSITION*INTERVAL_DIVISOR)-1, -2)/INTERVAL_DIVISOR) + (INTERVAL_WIDTH/2)) * SIGN(YPOSITION) AS HALF_INTERVAL
  FROM ctePositions
  CROSS JOIN cteConstants
```

Here the only thing you have to change is the value for `INTERVAL_WIDTH` in the first common table expression, and everything else is determined from that.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e74e3c7f3f6d48bc06a87867cddd2c2)

Comment: Thanks Bob, this has simplified my statement considerably. Do you know how I can derive a different INTERVAL_WIDTH for each model according to the grouping of points around a line?